# Eyelet replacement trace repair?

Tags: surface-mount

I'm new to electronics,  I was working on a surface mount board and I desoldered one of the eyelets a bit too much and burnt its trace as well. What steps should I take to repairing this? I'm not getting any continuity from the damaged vias. Thank you I Took pictures from both sides.

[image][image][image]

Comment: Also try to remove the fault that caused the pin to overheat in the first place.  With traces that thin the designer was not expecting a lot of current and something probably went wrong.  Possibly just a cold joint that should not reoccur.  Sorry, just realised you may have indicated that the damage was caused by your re-work in which case the repairs mentioned in the answer should be all you need.

Answer (score 1):

First, it is strongly recommended to clean the burned area using 99% isopropyl alcohol (IPA), and remove the burn mark as much as possible before attempting to fix the board, to prevent corrosive residue.

[image: IPA]

Some people would also apply fresh UV-curable solder mask liquid to cover the damaged parts of the board to protect it from additional damages, but it's often not necessary.

[image: Solder Mask]

After cleaning, solder a jumper wire to reconnect the broken trace. Example: Pad 1 and Pad 2 are connected by Trace 1, which is broken. You can install a new component and solder it as usual, but then solder an additional wire from Pad 1 and Pad 2 to complete the circuit. Usually, you can follow the trace visually. But still, it would be the best if you have a schematic, or a known-good board, and/or an understanding of the circuitry, especially for multilayer boards, so you can check where the trace is going to.

I find AWG-30 wirewrap wire is useful for these repairs, just make sure to get a wirestripper.

[image: AWG-30]

For smaller components/boards, you may need to use a "0.1mm PCB Link Jumper Wire". These wires are easy to break, but you don't need to remove the insulation before soldering, the soldering iron will melt the insulation.

[image: 0.1mm wire]

After soldering, reclean the board again to remove any flux residue, using 99% isopropyl alcohol (IPA).

You may want to glue the wire to secure it in-place. Hot-melt glue is not the best solution, but works reasonably well (make sure no other components is under the glue).

Comment: Thank you! I cleaned it with some rubbing alcohol and it looks much better. So I just have to repair the trace correct? Not the eyelet?

Comment: @Kushimaru In your case, only one connection is broken. You just need to solder a wire directly to the "leg" of your component, and solder the other side of the wire to the destination of the trace. For example, if the other side of the trace has a resistor, you can just solder the other side to that resistor. If it's a chip, you can use the 0.1mm wire. Another way to fix it, is using a knive to remove the paint (solder mask) so you can see the copper, and solder the leg of your component to the copper trace directly. See this video for an example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cTnVg6Pmf-U

Comment: I'm doing a bit of research  on the pcb link jumper wire. Some say they are magnet, should I go with these or no? Also I'm reading that I should tin the copper wire. Should I buy it already tinned or just buy the one you recommend?

Comment: @Kushimaru Yes, they are magnet wire, which means they are often used in magnetic components such as transformers, but they are useful wires and you can use it for other purposes. "I should tin the copper wire" just apply the tin with your soldering iron. "Should I buy it already tinned or just buy the one you recommend?" It's just a piece of wire, you can use whatever you are comfortable working with, just spend some time practicing with it.